# RHEL 7.2: using realm to join AD domain

Tags: linux, active-directory

I have a fresh install of RHEL 7.2 server, and I'd like to join it to an AD domain. I have pre-staged the computer name in AD, and here's what happens when I follow the instructions in the *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Windows Integration Guide*.

I'm using split DNS in my department: the authoritative campus-wide DNS servers are running BIND and do *not* support dynamic updating, so I run a pair of Windows DNS servers in my department.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

```
[root@dept-example ~]# realm discover -v example.edu
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.example.edu
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.0.2.177
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.0.2.176
 * Successfully discovered: example.edu
example.edu
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: EXAMPLE.EDU
  domain-name: example.edu
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common
[root@dept-example ~]# realm join example.edu -v -U 'example.edu\adm-jsmith'
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.example.edu
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.0.2.176
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.0.2.178
 * Successfully discovered: example.edu
Password for example.edu\adm-jsmith:
 * Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/bin/net
 * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.K4T3EY -U fsu.edu\adm-jsmith ads join example.edu
Enter example.edu\adm-jsmith's password:
Using short domain name -- EXAMPLE
Joined 'DEPT-EXAMPLE' to dns domain 'example.edu'
 * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.K4T3EY -U example.edu\adm-jsmith ads keytab create
Enter example.edu\adm-jsmith's password:kerberos_kinit_password example.edu\adm-jsmith@EXAMPLE.EDU failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
kerberos_kinit_password example.edu\adm-jsmith@EXAMPLE.EDU failed: Client not found in Kerberos database

 ! Extracting host keytab failed
realm: Couldn't join realm: Extracting host keytab failed
[root@dept-example ~]#
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same error message trying to join an AD domain on a CentOS 7.2 server.  However, contrary to the directions, passing just the username worked for me:

```
realm join example.edu -v -U 'adm-jsmith'
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried many things until I saw the answer above just using the user name.  That was the key.  I kept getting a kerberos failure to find kdc and a kerberos failure to authenticate messages until I used the following:

```
realm --verbose join -U 'administrator' host.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have set `/etc/resolv.conf` file as per your domain name.Can you try like below using caps for Domain.com

```
realm join -U adm-jsmith@EXAMPLE.EDU <givedomaincontrollerip> -v
```

Please post the o/p if you get any error.